# How to connect a custom built wallet to in-app browser?

Tags: react-native, metamask, ethers.js, wallet

I am building a wallet app with React Native using ethers.js.

I would like to let my app function as a wallet provider to any web3 website as soon as the in-app expo-webbrowser (or any web view or browser) is opened, and the user clicks on a “connect to wallet” button.

```
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://sparklesnft.com/',{
  dismissButtonStyle: "close",
  toolbarColor: vars.themes[theme].themeColor,
  readerMode: true,
  enableBarCollapsing: false,
  showTitle: true,
  secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
  controlsColor: '#ffffff'
});
```

I am not sure how I inject my wallet provider into the browser. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: So you're looking to have your app function as a wallet for other dapps?

Answer (score 0):

Well since no one else has given you an answer, I'll just give you everything I've found. I think you might be looking for [@walletconnect/ethereum-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/ethereum-provider).

I also found some info on creating an app that connects to these wallets. Maybe that will get you in the right direction.

[W3-react](https://github.com/Uniswap/web3-react)

[Integrating with Web3-React](https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/wallet-sdk/docs/web3-react)